# Liferay: can't deploy module. Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(osgi.ee=UNKNOWN)"

Tags: java, liferay

I recently started Liferay development and I'm following the official developer guide, but I'm having trouble when trying to deploy a simple hello world module.

When I try to deploy the module, Eclipse console shows the following exception:

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:
>   com.liferay.docs.guestbook.portlet [1000]_  Unresolved requirement:
>   Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(osgi.ee=UNKNOWN)"_ [Sanitized]

I'm stuck at this point, and don't know what to do. I tried using different Eclipse versions, I tried changing projects' Java build path to use JRE 1.8, I tried deleting the project and creating a new one...

I also used the command "ss" to list the modules, but apparently my module isn't listed.

I'm under Ubuntu 18.04 and using Eclipse 2018-12 build.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you create and build your module project? Are you using blade CLI and a liferay workspace. Do you have a plugin for Eclipse or are you launching gradle build inside the IDE? What is mentioned as UNKNOWN in you filter is usually the Java Version (in my case: `osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))` )

Comment: I'm using Eclipse with Liferay plugin. I created a Liferay Workspace Project (File > New > Liferay Workspace Project) and then inside this project I created a Liferay Module Project. I did it the same way as here: https://dev.liferay.com/es/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/writing-your-first-liferay-application

Comment: Could you verify that there is no Java 10 involved in your environment (starting, eclipse, running gradle tasks and so on). Otherwise, you might need to upgrade your bnd plugin version

Comment: I've set both workspace and module build paths to JavaSE-1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I was using Eclipse + Liferay on an Ubuntu VM, then I switched to my host machine (W10) and installed Oracle JDK and module was deployed correctly.

So I guess the problem was using JRE instead of full JDK.